Rollup bundle ES6 does not exports classes
I'm currently woking on a API-Client library coded with typescript. In my index.ts file I have the next piece of code:
//index.ts

export * from "./api";
export * from "./configuration";

Inside the api module I have a class exported like this:
//api.ts

export class MyClass{}

My tsconfig has the next configuration. I need the module field has the Commonjs value.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./generated",

    "declarationDir": "./dist/types",
    "declaration": true,

    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}


So, my intention is having this library bundled as:

CommonJs
ES6 modules

To do this I use Rollup. To achivieve this goal, first I compile the code I have with typescript. As my configuration says that the compiled code needs to be in CommonJS I have the goal number 1, I dont need the rollup configuration to do this.
To have the second goal, I use the @rollup/plugin-commonjs in order to transpile the compiled typescript code (commonjs) to a ES6 file. This is my rollup configuration:
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";

const config = [
  {
    input: "./dist/index.js",

    output: [
      {
        file: "./lib/index.cjs",
        exports: "named",
        interop: "auto",
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: "./lib/index.mjs",
        format: "es",
        interop: "auto",
        exports: "named",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],

    plugins: [nodeResolve(), commonjs()],
    external: ["axios"],
  },
];

export default config;

With this config I supposed the dist/index.js code will be in ES6 format I could use MyClass in my host application like this:
import {MyClass} from "mybundledlibrary"

But I get this error in my console:
The requested module does not provide an export named MyClass

My Package.json configuration looks like this:
 "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "./lib",
    "./dist"
  ],
  "exports": {
    "require": "./lib/index.cjs",
    "import": "./lib/index.mjs"
  },




I dont know how I need to configure the code from CommonJS to ES6 with the named exports like MyClass and use it in other applications.

Why are you bundling? Is this running on a server? Seems like bundling is unnecessary unless this is a lambda on aws or something. Can you share a link to the repo?
